# AngularJS $Modal itself is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Im trying to make my first modal using Angular, but it seems that the `$modal` cant even be found! Here is my code:

```
myController = ($scope, $modal) ->
  $scope.OpenModal = ->$modal.open(
    templateUrl: 'Modal.html'
  )
```

And the HTML points to the `OpenModal` function as follows -

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-click="OpenModal()">Modal</button>
</div>
```

But when I click the button, I get the error `Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`. Why is that? Shouldn't the `modal` object be injected in?

Comment: Have you injected bootstrap into your app?

Comment: Should .open parameters be an object?, I'm not familiar with Coffeescript.

Comment: seems you forgot to include ui.bootstrap module into your module: angular.module('yourappmodule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had already included `ui.bootstrap` in my app, but I forgot to put `$modal` in the controller dependencies.

Comment: That's weird since it looks like it's being injected from your previous code.