# Modal Using AngularJS not opening, getting TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a simple modal using Angular. I want it to open from an "About" link in my navbar. Here's the html:

```
            <div ng-controller = "ModalDemoCtrl">
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">I am a modal!</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1>Welcome to my modal</h1>
                </div>
            </script>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#" ng-click="open()">About</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

And here is my Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('chucknorris', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);


app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {

    $scope.open = $modal.open({templateUrl:'myModalContent.html'});
}]);
```

I'm not trying to process or pass any data into the model, so I think just open should work. I looked at this SO question [AngularJS $Modal itself is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106023/angularjs-modal-itself-is-undefined), but I'm pretty sure I'm including $modal correctly. I just need a modal to open, it was so easy in bootstrap.js. Thanks for any help.

*** Edit *** 
Here's the full error message I'm getting:
    at link (http://youtoocanbechucknorris.com/js/ui-bootstrap.js:8:26380)
    at U (http://youtoocanbechucknorris.com/js/angularmin.js:48:226)
    at k (http://youtoocanbechucknorris.com/js/angularmin.js:42:309)
    at U (http://youtoocanbechucknorris.com/js/angularmin.js:48:167)
    at k (http://youtoocanbechucknorris.com/js/angularmin.js:42:309)
    at U (http://youtoocanbechucknorris.com/js/angularmin.js:48:167)
    at http://youtoocanbechucknorris.com/js/angularmin.js:53:483
    at http://youtoocanbechucknorris.com/js/angularmin.js:64:351
    at y (http://youtoocanbechucknorris.com/js/angularmin.js:89:187)
    at y (http://youtoocanbechucknorris.com/js/angularmin.js:89:187)

Comment: Could you provide a plnkr or fiddle? It would be easier to detect the issue.

Comment: I just created a plnker, and it works there. So my problem must be elsewhere. Here is the plnker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TDsrm90lrshcXCZCkQlR. +1 for getting me out of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was the version of Angular I was using. I was using a copy of Angular I downloaded not 6 months ago. When I downloaded the latest version everything worked. From the docs angular-ui "requires AngularJS 1.2.x, tested with 1.2.16". I was using an early version of 1.2, which I guess didn't cover everything. 1.2.26 works like a charm. Keeping myself up to date would have saved me half a day of work. Lesson learned. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yep, I found an issue like this when I tried to create a plnkr too :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `$scope.open = $modal.open({templateUrl:'myModalContent.html'});` to

```
$scope.open = function() {
    $modal.open({templateUrl:'myModalContent.html'})
};
```

Comment: I wish I could accept this but I'm still getting the same error message. It's like it doesn't know what $modal is, but I'm sure ui.bootstrap is loading correctly. I'll edit my question to include the full error message. Thanks.

Comment: Are you bringing in the angular-ui/bootstrap library?